# How to call a Javascript function from multiple Ant targets?

Tags: javascript, ant

I have a javascript function that I would like to define once in a Ant build file thant call it in multiple targets without having to redfine it within each target.

Here is my function:

```js
divs = project.getProperty("division").split(",");

runMacro = function(macro_name) {

     for (i=0; i < divs.length; i++)
   {

     try {

 if (typeof(divs[i]) != "undefined" && divs[i] != "" && divs[i] !== null) {

  macro = project.createTask(macro_name);

  macro.setDynamicAttribute("division", divs[i]);
  macro.setDynamicAttribute("application-version", "${app-version}");
  macro.perform();

 } else {

  throw "Divison name cannot be null.";

 } 


}
 catch (error) {

  print("Something went wrong: ", error);


 }

}

}
```

I would like to call it from any target in the Ant build.xml

```html
<target name="app-status" description="." >
  <script language="javascript">
   <![CDATA[


myScript.runMacro("get-app-status");



 ]]>
  </script>
 </target>
```

Is there a way yo define the JS function as global in the Ant script?

Thank you!

Comment: The easy thing to do here would be just to make a `<macrodef>` in your script that only contains your script, then call it in Ant whenever you need to use it. There's a good chance whatever you're trying to do in your JS script is already possible with Ant, though. Simply using native Ant tasks would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CAustin.

You are right, this can be achieved using Scriptdef.

I did not try it yet, but the code would be something like:

```
 <scriptdef name="process-divsion" language="javascript">
      <attribute name="macro-name"/>

      <![CDATA[


        divs = project.getProperty('division').split(','); 


       for (i=0; i < divs.length; i++)
       {


     try {

      print("Processing divison: ", divs[i]);

     if (typeof(divs[i]) != "undefined" && divs[i] != "" && divs[i] !== null) {
        macro = project.createTask(attributes.get("macro-name"));

         macro.setDynamicAttribute( "division", divs[i]);

         macro.perform();
         }

         else {

       throw "Division name cannot be null.";

      }
       }

       catch (error) {

      print("Something went wrong: ", error);


     }

       }


      ]]>
    </scriptdef>
```

Then it can be called anywhere in the build.xml

```
<target name="app-status" >
<process-division macro-name="get-app-status"  />
</target>
```